How to run code across scenes in Godot? A code that runs all or multiple scenes
Im new to Godot and I'm trying to build a simple farming game.
My question is how can I have some codes that run across the scenes.
I'm trying to learn different ways to do it so I can decide which one is best for this game and later games I may build.
So lets say I have a scene that is the farm and player can plant vegetables in the farm and water them etc. but then the player may leave the scene and go like shopping etc.
But while he is on another scene I want to have a code running that make changes to the farm scene data, like vegetables etc. BUT also I want this code to be accessible and running across scenes. (I know I can use global variables by making a globals.gd autoload)
But what about having some code running across the scenes?
I would like to know the solution for general situation/different situations.
I did some searching but I could only find about 1 solution and that is having 1 scene for the whole game and changing scenes would be like loading different scenes inside the main scene. Any other/better solution?
Thanks

What you found is, as far as I know, the recommended way of going about it. In Godot a scene is still a node, and the idea is that you have a main scene as the parent, with a game manager script attached to it, and then you switch out the child scenes as needed.

The better way to do this is to use Singletons
These will load in all you scenes and carry variables and signals. For your farmer example it will be easy to use a SignalBus autoload node to transmit the bought upgrades to your farm scene as parameters.
With this said, i STRONGLY recommend reading the full documentation
1: https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/singletons_autoload.html

